# Fill pattern of an arbitrary size in Intel hex file

Tags: algorithm, file, embedded, hex

I have been trying to do a fill using the open source [Srecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) Program. I need to do a fill that is 
`0xC2AF00`. It appears the program can only do fills that are a byte long (ex: `0xff`). If this is not possible with the  [Srecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) program, then how would I go about writing my own algorithm to do what I want?

I am not quite sure how to determine what needs a fill and then how I would proceed to go about doing the fill that is needed.  And on the off chance that someone could answer the same question for a Tektronix file, that would be just as good or better than how to do what I am asking for on the Intel hex file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -repeat-data generator can take multiple bytes as parameters.
The following will fill bytes 16 through 31 with C2AF00C2AF00...

```
srec_cat -Output -Intel -generate 0x10 0x20 -repeat-data 0xC2 0xAF 0x00
```

Combine with your actual input, or other generators, to fill the appropriate ranges.

Comment: I had never touched SRecord until you posted this question.  I just started developing for AVR microcontrollers, and I recognized your question as something I would want to be able to do soon (produced pattern fills for my EEPROM images), so it seemed like the perfect time to go manpage digging.

Comment: I can not seem to get it to work still. I will digg further and let you know as well. the problem is I can not seem to get generate to work ... it give me an error. Oh well I will play and post back.
Thanks again. (I too today found the relevant section of the srecord of file.)

Comment: my last sentence should have been at the end 'srecord pdf file'

Comment: I am stupid it is all in the manual:
./srec_cat ulc14_04.hex --ignore-checksums -o -intel /
 -linelength 75 ulc14_04.hex 

  Then


./srec_cat ulc14_04.hex  -intel \
> -generate '(' 0x0000 0xFFFE -minus -within ulc14_04.hex -intel ')' \
> -repeat-data 0xC2 0xAF 0x00 \
>  -o ulc14_04.hex  -intel